# SQL error 1064: syntax error using contains

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use operator contains in my query but I get this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'contains             (select ssn             from Musicians M2             where' at line 6

My query is supposed to get all instrIDs played by every musician named John. meaning all johns used this instrument. 
It says it's a syntax error and I don't know where is the error.
and this is my sql query:

```
select instrID
from Plays P
where (
  select ssn 
  from Musicians M
  where M.ssn = P.ssn
) contains (
  select ssn
  from Musicians M2
  where M.aname = 'John'
)
```

Comment: What is this query supposed to do?

Comment: Can you try this one - `select instrID
from Plays P
where ((select ssn 
            from Musicians M
            where M.ssn = P.ssn)
            contains
            (select ssn
            from Musicians M2
            where M.aname = 'John'))`

Comment: Maybe add some sample data for the two tables if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather complicated.  I would approach this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.instrID
from Plays p join
     Musicians m
     on m.ssn = p.ssn
where m.aname = 'John'
group by p.instrID
having count(*) = (select count(*) from Musicians m2 where m2.aname = 'John');
```

The `having` clause fulfills the requirement that *all* musicians named "John" play the instrument.

Answer (score 1):

The `CONTAINS` MySQL keyword is only applicable when dealing with spatial data, so it should not work with your current query.

I suspect that all you really need here is a simple join:

```
SELECT p.instrID
FROM Plays p
INNER JOIN Musicians m
    ON p.ssn = m.ssn
WHERE m.aname = 'John';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do join like this:

```
select p.instrID
from Plays P, Musicians m
where p.ssn = m.ssn
and m.aname = 'John';
```

Depending upon the requirement, you may try `left outer join`, `right outer join` etc.

Comment: you should use explicit join

Comment: No such standard of explicit join. Both joins perform same explicit or implicit

Comment: comma separated join makes it cross join - when you join tables its better to explicitly define like inner join/join/left join/right join/full join this way

Comment: no no such standard. inner join can be implemented using "=". its not better..its same..

Answer (score 0):

You can do other case

```
Select instrID
from Plays P
where P.ssn in (
  select ssn 
  from Musicians M
  where 
  M.aname='John');
```